# Installing third Application Replacing my first Application in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 3 applications made by me lets say X1,Y1 and Z1.Now installation of two application X1 and Y1 is successful but when i am installing Z1 then its replacing my X1 application.can you guys help me in this issue.any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the package name for 2 apps the same?

Comment: it the package struture is sane

Comment: Yeah for two of the Application Package Name is same.

Comment: this is because two application have same package name that's why i was facing this Problem.

Comment: Yep, you can't have two different apps with same package naame installed on a device.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

read this

It names the Java package for the application. The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.